# Import macro to excel using open xml

Tags: c#, vba, openxml

I am able to copy a vbaproject part from xlsm to another xlsm through memory stream and add it through addnew part. Is there any possibility to import/add only the bas file into the xlsm file using open xml. Can some one assist.Below code helped to take a clone of vba part and update the same.
`private static void cloneVbaPart(string src, string dst) { using (WordprocessingDocument srcDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(src, false)){ var vbaPart = srcDoc.MainDocumentPart.VbaProjectPart; using (WordprocessingDocument dstDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(dst, true)) { var partsToRemove = new List(); foreach (var part in dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType()) { partsToRemove.Add(part); } foreach (var part in dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType()) { partsToRemove.Add(part); } foreach (var part in partsToRemove) { dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.DeletePart(part); } var vbaProjectPart = dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart(); var vbaDataPart = vbaProjectPart.AddNewPart(); using (Stream data = vbaPart.GetStream()) { vbaProjectPart.FeedData(data); } using (Stream data = vbaPart.VbaDataPart.GetStream()) { vbaDataPart.FeedData(data); } } }`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I m looking on how to add macro code(new module) in to an existing xlsm file. is it possible through open xml